# Expected value the device corrupts

Tags: self-study, dataset, random-variable, conditional-probability, continuous-data

An electronic device has two circuits $(C1, C2)$. $C2$ is a backup circuit and starts to work only when $C1$ is corrupted. If $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables indicating lifetime of $C1$ and $C2$, and we have:
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{24}{(x+y)^4},  & \text{x,y > 1} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
What is the expected value the device corrupts?

I'm not sure what exactly i need to calculate. Is it $E(Y|X = x)$? Which is the expected value of $C2$ lifetime if $C1$ is corrupted. 
If i'm right, i also need to figure out $f_X(x)$. Any idea how can i do this?

Comment: Not sure exactly what is meant by "expected value the device corrupts", but you can find $f_X(x)$ using marginalization, $f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{24}{(x+y)^4} dy = \frac{8}{(y+1)^3}$ using integration by substitution. To get here use the substitution $u=x+y$.

Answer (score 0):

If your question can be translated to the expected lifetime of the electronic device, then that would be the expected value of the maximum of $X$ and $Y$.

$$\int _1^{\infty }\int _1^{\infty }\frac{24\max (x,y)}{(x+y)^4}dydx$$
$$=\int _1^{\infty }\int _1^x\frac{24y}{(x+y)^4}dxdy+\int _1^{\infty }\int _1^y\frac{24x}{(x+y)^4}dydx$$
$$=4$$